# Supervisord commands to start rsyslog and haproxy

Tags: supervisord

I've been trying to get these two to start when my docker image starts but they never seem to start.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:rsyslog]
command=/bin/bash "service rsyslog start"

[program:haproxy]
command=/bin/bash "service haproxy start"
```

What command is needed to start both in the order of rsyslog first then haproxy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:rsyslog]
command=service rsyslog start

[program:haproxy]
command=service haproxy start
```

However, now I must delay starting haproxy as haproxy requires rsyslog to be started before hand. This however is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work because `service ... start` command starts the programm as daemon and sends it in the background. The `supervisord` can't deal with that rather it needs to start them as subprocess and run them in forground. See [here](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html):

> Programs meant to be run under supervisor *should not daemonize*
>   themselves. Instead, they *should run in the foreground*. They should
>   not detach from the terminal from which they are started.
>   The easiest way to tell if a program will run in the foreground is to
>   run the command that invokes the program from a shell prompt. If it
>   gives you control of the terminal back, but continues running, it’s
>   daemonizing itself and that will almost certainly be the wrong way to
>   run it under supervisor. You want to run a command that essentially
>   requires you to press Ctrl-C to get control of the terminal back. If
>   it gives you a shell prompt back after running it without needing to
>   press Ctrl-C, it’s not useful under supervisor. All programs have
>   options to be run in the foreground but there’s no “standard way” to
>   do it; you’ll need to read the documentation for each program.

Here is  a “real world” program configuration example from [supervisord documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html):

Apache 2.2.6:

```
[program:apache2]
command=/path/to/httpd -c "ErrorLog /dev/stdout" -DFOREGROUND
redirect_stderr=true
```

Your programm's startup scripts can be a good place to find out how the program starts, for proper configuration.

Some examples are [here](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html)

Answer (score -1):

You need to put something like that, just adjust parameters

```
[program:rsyslog]
command=/sbin/rsyslogd -n -a /var/run/systemd/journal/syslog
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Regards,