# Starting supervisord results in failure

Tags: supervisord

My `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:rsyslog]
command=service rsyslog start
startsecs 5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I get the error:

```
root@haproxy:/# /usr/bin/supervisord
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
Error: File contains parsing errors: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
    [line  6]: 'startsecs 5\n'
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Comment: Did you actually read my answer on your recent question?: http://serverfault.com/questions/738858/supervisord-commands-to-start-rsyslog-and-haproxy

Comment: @bangal I did, I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error log carefully.

> Error: File contains parsing errors:
>   /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
>       [line  6]: 'startsecs 5\n'

You have syntax error in line 6:

```
startsecs 5
```

It should be `startsecs=5`